# Does my function run in O(n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a function to find if there are numbers in a sorted array `s` which add up to a given sum `x`. I want to know what the big-Oh complexity is for this function. I think it runs in O(n) but I am not sure.

Function:

```
def sumInside(s, x):
    # Two indices that will be compared
    l = 0
    r = len(s) - 1

    # Go through the array for the elements
    while l < r:
        if s[l] + s[r] == x:
            return True
        elif s[l] + s[r] < x:
            l += 1
        else:
            r -= 1
    return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two rules of thumb:

1. How many iterations over your data?
2. What happens per iteration?

The answer to the first question is `n`. You have one loop, and it iterates over the entirety of your data once.

The second question is also easily answered. You have comparisons taking place in each loop, which is a constant time operation.

Overall, your function runs in linear time in the worst case - `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `O(n)` Worst case

Worst case scenario, your element is to the far right (l must increment all the way to the right), that will be `n` times.

If it is to the far left `O(1)`, you find it on your first try. When `l = 0`.

Let's say theoretically, average case x is always in the middle, it would take n/2 iterations which is `O(n)`.

- Best: `O(1)`
- Avg: `O(n)`
- Worst: `O(n)`